# Use the laws of logic to simplify the expression

Tags: logic

Use the laws of logic to simplify the expression
P∨¬(¬P→Q)

Comment: The cheaty way would be to do a simple truth table. You would find out that the expression if false only when $P$ is false and $Q$ is true. This would give $\neg (\neg P \wedge Q) = P \vee \neg Q$.

Comment: This question shows zero effort and does not describe what the OP is having problems with.

Answer (score 2):

$p\lor \overline{(\overline{p}→q)}$

$=p\lor \overline{(\overline{\overline{p}}\lor q)}$

$=p\lor \overline{(p\lor q)}$

$=p\lor (\overline{p}\land \overline{q})$

$=(p\lor \overline{p})\land (p\lor \overline{q})$

$=T\land (p\lor \overline{q})$

$=(p\lor \overline{q})$

$=q→p$

Answer (score 0):

This question is a trap.

Either $P$ is true, or (Not $P$) doesn't imply $Q$

However it's a mistake to make the leap to say that this is equivalent to:

Either $P$ is true, or (Not $P$) implies $(Q$ is false).

If $P$ is false then $Q$ can be indeterminate - since all we know is that $Q$'s truth is not explicitly implied.

Therefore it simplifies to simply $P$.

Comment: No, it's not. When both $P$ and $Q$ are **f**, we have that $¬(¬P→Q)$ is **t**, and thus also $P∨¬(¬P→Q)$ is.

Comment: Is "Not (A implies B)" equivalent to "(A doesn't imply B)"?